# What does $(x)$ mean in the context of ring theory?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, ideals

My problem booklet (Mathematics BSc, 2nd year Algebra module, unpublished) has,

> Let $R=\{a+b\epsilon:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$, with the multiplication rule $\epsilon^2=0$. [...] Describe $R$ as the quotient of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ by some ideal.

The solution booklet has,

$$R \simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2).$$

I see $(x^2)$ should refer to an ideal, but I don't recognise the notation. Can someone clarify?

Comment: $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ just means the ideal generated by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.  In your case $(x^2)$ means the ideal generated by $x^2$.

Comment: @tkf Would you mind defining what that generated ideal is in this case? I haven't quite got this. Are we talking about something like $\{ax^2:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: It is all elements of the form $\lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2+\ldots+ \lambda_n a_n$, where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are elements of the ring.  For example in $\mathbb{Z}$, $(2)$ denotes the even numbers.

Comment: @tkf So in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ does $(x^2)=\{x^2\cdot a_0 + x^2\cdot a_1x + \dots x^2 \cdot a_nx^n: a_0 \dots a_n \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ a_0x^2 + a_1x^3 + \dots + a_nx^{n+2}: a_0\dots a_n \in \mathbb{R} \}$?

Comment: Yes exactly that set of elements.  Note that if we quotient by this, then every element is equivalent to one of the form $a+bx$, and $x^2=0$.

Comment: @tkf I think I've got it... sort of. Thanks for your help.